# Endnotes in two columns: how to have \section in one column?

Tags: sectioning, multicol, endnotes

I have a document with endotes which should be typeset in two columns. This works fine with the code in the MWE below.

How can I interrupt the twocolumn-area for the section headings? I want them to be typeset in one column.

```
    \documentclass[10pt]{scrbook}
    \usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
    \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
    \usepackage{multicol,endnotes,lipsum}

    \begin{document}

    \section*{Section 1}
    \addtoendnotes{\protect\subsection*{Endotes S1}}
    \lipsum\endnote{Endnote in section 1:\lipsum}

    \section*{Section 2}
    \addtoendnotes{\protect\subsection*{Endotes S2}}
    \lipsum\endnote{Endnote in section 2:\lipsum}

    \newpage
    \begin{multicols}{2}
    \theendnotes
    \end{multicols}

    \end{document}
```

Comment: Sorry, `endnotes` has some strange coding. Perhaps you should look for a more up-to-date package

Comment: Would you mind pointing in some direction, which package is the right up-to-date one for putting notes at the end of a document?

Comment: Sorry, I have no such recommendation