# Two-column endnotes with one-column header

Tags: multicol, endnotes, enotez

I already did try it some time ago

[Endnotes in two columns: how to have \section in one column?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/235846/endnotes-in-two-columns-how-to-have-section-in-one-column)

but I was not able to find a solution yet. This is what I am looking for:

Endnotes that are (a) numbered chapter-wise, (b) typeset in two columns, (c) have the chapter-titles as their header, which (d) is typeset in one column.

Here is my example:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{enotez,multicol}
\usepackage{kantlipsum,mwe}

\EnotezCurrentSplitTitle
\setenotez{list-name={},
reset = true,
split = chapter,
split-sectioning = {chapter},
split-heading = {\chapter*{#1}},
split-title={}
}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Erstes Kapitel}
Text\endnote{\kant[1]}. Text\endnote{\kant[2]}.     
Text\endnote{\kant[3];\kant[4]}.
Text\endnote{\kant[5];\kant[6]}.

\chapter{Zweites Kapitel}

Text\endnote{\kant[1]}. Text\endnote{\kant[2]}.    
Text\endnote{\kant[3];\kant[4]}.
Text\endnote{\kant[5];\kant[6]}.

\newpage

\appendix
\begin{multicols}{2}
\printendnotes
\end{multicols}
\end{document}

\end{document}
```

I am not stuck with the enotez package. Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

EDIT:
I try to show the result:

## Endnotes

1st chapter (heading in one column)

1. Endnote in left column.         2. Endnote in right column.

2nd chapter (heading in one column)

1. Endnote in left column.         2. Endnote in right column.

Comment: When looking for a solution to this I found several severe bugs when typesetting the splitted titles. I will fix them, send the update to CTAN and will post an answer then.

Comment: By “have the chapter-titles as their header” do you mean if you have `\chapter{My cool chapter}` then you want `My cool chapter` as heading in the endnotes list, too?

Comment: Yes, it is the heding/title of the chapter in the main text which I want to subdivide the endnotes as well. I edited my question and hope to be more clear now.

Comment: The structure is clear. What still isn't clear: `enotez` would put “Notes for chapter <number>” as headings at each split level. Do you want that or the argument you used as argument for the corresponding `\chapter` in the document?

Comment: The latter: I want “my cool chapter“ as title of the split.

Comment: OK. This will require a package like `nameref`, `titleref` or `zref` and some labels... I'll try to come up with somthing...

Comment: That would be great, thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I uploaded v0.8 to CTAN yesterday wich includes the necessary fixes so the `\AtEveryEndnotesList`, `\AtEveryListSplit` (and related) hooks work as advertised.

The idea is to use these hooks to begin and end `mulicols` around the list excluding the headings:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{enotez,multicol}
\usepackage{kantlipsum,microtype}

\setenotez{
  reset = true,
  split = chapter,
}

\AtEveryEndnotesList{\begin{multicols}{2}} % before the whole list
\AfterEveryEndnotesList{\end{multicols}}   % after the whole list
\AfterEveryListSplit{\begin{multicols}{2}} % after a sub-heading in the splitted list
\AtEveryListSplit{\end{multicols}}         % before a sub-heading in the splitted list

% column sep between columns in a multicols env:
\setlength\columnsep{22pt}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Superduper}
Text\endnote{\kant[1]}. Text\endnote{\kant[2]}.     
Text\endnote{\kant[3];\kant[4]}.
Text\endnote{\kant[5];\kant[6]}.

\chapter{Eher langweilig}
Text\endnote{\kant[1]}. Text\endnote{\kant[2]}.    
Text\endnote{\kant[3];\kant[4]}.
Text\endnote{\kant[5];\kant[6]}.

\newpage

\appendix
\chapter*{Anmerkungen}
\printendnotes

\end{document}
```

[image]

Getting the actual chapter headings as sub-headings for the list requires more work: we need a package like [`zref`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/zref) and its `titleref` module, `\label`s at *every* chapter and a possibility to `\ref` the labels in the sub-headings:

With `\usepackage[user,titleref]{zref}` we can use `\zlabel{<label>}` after `\chapter's and use`\ztitleref{}` to get the corresponding chapter-title. In order not have the labels manually all the time we can do something like this:

```
\usepackage{xparse}
\let\oldchapter\chapter
\RenewDocumentCommand\chapter{som}{%
  \IfBooleanTF{#1}
    {\oldchapter*{#3}}
    {%
      \IfNoValueTF{#2}
        {\oldchapter{#3}}
        {\oldchapter[#2]{#3}}%
      \zlabel{ch:\arabic{chapter}}%
    }%
}
```

which places a zlabel `ch:<num>` every time `\chapter` is used. With the new `\NewSplitTitleTag` macro of `enotez` we can now get the chapter titles as in the subheadings:

```
\NewSplitTitleTag{chapter title}{\ztitleref{ch:<split-level-id>}}
\setenotez{
  reset = true,
  split = chapter,
  split-title = {<name> <ref>: <chapter title>}
}
```

[image]

The complete code:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{enotez}[2015/06/24]
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{kantlipsum,microtype}

\usepackage[user,titleref]{zref}
\usepackage{xparse}
\let\oldchapter\chapter
\RenewDocumentCommand\chapter{som}{%
  \IfBooleanTF{#1}
    {\oldchapter*{#3}}
    {%
      \IfNoValueTF{#2}
        {\oldchapter{#3}}
        {\oldchapter[#2]{#3}}%
      \zlabel{ch:\arabic{chapter}}%
    }%
}

\NewSplitTitleTag{chapter title}{\ztitleref{ch:<split-level-id>}}
\setenotez{
  reset = true,
  split = chapter,
  split-title = {<name> <ref>: <chapter title>}
}

\AtEveryEndnotesList{\begin{multicols}{2}} % before the whole list
\AfterEveryEndnotesList{\end{multicols}}   % after the whole list
\AfterEveryListSplit{\begin{multicols}{2}} % after a sub-heading in the splitted list
\AtEveryListSplit{\end{multicols}}         % before a sub-heading in the splitted list

% column sep between columns in a multicols env:
\setlength\columnsep{22pt}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Superduper}
Text\endnote{\kant[1]}. Text\endnote{\kant[2]}.     
Text\endnote{\kant[3];\kant[4]}.
Text\endnote{\kant[5];\kant[6]}.

\chapter{Eher langweilig}
Text\endnote{\kant[1]}. Text\endnote{\kant[2]}.    
Text\endnote{\kant[3];\kant[4]}.
Text\endnote{\kant[5];\kant[6]}.

\newpage

\appendix
\printendnotes

\end{document}
```

Comment: I am overwhelmed - will try it out over the weekend. Thank you in advance!

Comment: @michael did you test it?

Comment: Not yet, sorry, I'm stuck in steps in between. But I'm trying in one of the next evenings, curious myself.

Comment: May there be a incompatibility with `SCfigure`? As far as I can see with a quick glance, this is the relevant error I get. More tomorrow evening, I hope.

Comment: @michael are you using endnotes *in* a figure? In a caption maybe? This isn't really supported well. But it isn't part of the question, either, is it? What I am interested in is if my code (as I posted it) works. New problems due to other packages etc. may be worth a new question and new answers.

Comment: No, there are no endnotes in figures. I'll work out two MWE: one with and one without `SCfigure`.

Comment: @michael I just checked for myself: as long as no `\endnote` is used inside `\caption` there is noc conflict whatsowever bewteen `enotez` and `sidecap`.

Comment: No, there are no endnotes in figures. I'll work out two MWE, one with and one without `SCfigure`. [Sorry for using the wrong button.]

Comment: I found the reason for the errors: I have to use `\newline` instead of \\ inside of captions. Now the document compiles without errors. – But one other thing needs more research: The references to the chapters don't work, I only get "Kapitel 0: ??" Maybe because I use `\include` to combine the separate documents into one?

Comment: I think the problem with the references is my following redefinition: `\makeatletter
\renewcommand\chapter{\@startsection 
 {chapter}{0}{0mm}
 {4\baselineskip}
 {2\baselineskip}
 {\normalfont\large\center}}
\makeatother

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{-2}` -- @clemens: Do you have an idea how to solve this? I mark the question as answered bcause you did give a wonderful solution (only my document is very special).

Comment: @michael yes: your chapters have no counter so the counter value of the `chapter` counter always has the value `0`. As a consequence the labels produced with `\zlabel{ch:\arabic{chapter}}` all are `ch:0` which means multiply defined labels. You can add `\refstepcounter{chapter}` to the redefinition of `\chapter` in my example right before `\zlabel`. (Of course you need to ensure that *your* redefinition takes place before mine.  Even better: combine both redefinitions into one.)

Comment: BTW: `\center` is not a valid LaTeX command. It is a command used internally by the `center` environment.

Comment: It works!! Thank you, Clemens, you are my hero ;-) Now I can start with formatting the endnotes, but the related questions (if there are going to be any) would be a new topic ...

Comment: Sorry for bothering you again: Is there a way to use `\chapter*`? When I do so, I get "???" as split-titles. I tried but could not figure it out by myself.