# enotez package: how to format split section headings?

Tags: formatting, endnotes, enotez

This is a follow-up to:
[Two-column endnotes with one-column header](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/251427/two-column-endnotes-with-one-column-header)

Clemens' answer is exactly what I needed. But there is another wish: Given the chapter ttles are ragged right in the main text, but I want to have them centered as the split title in the endnotes.

I tried this:

```
\setenotez{
list-name = {},
reset = true,
split = chapter,
split-title = {\centering <chapter title>},
mark-cs = {\textsuperscript}
}
```

but only got errors:

[image]

Any ideas? Thank you once again.

Comment: A complete example would be useful.

Comment: Essentially that means you want two `\section`s (or two `\chapter`s) with different formatting – one for the text and one for the list. So the question is really how to do that. Once you figured that out just use the `split-heading` option to use that command.

Comment: Thank you, @Clemens, for showing me the right directiion. I Think I have worked out a solution and will post it shortly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, this is what I found out, thanks to Clemens' comment (and, of course, his big help in the first question concerning enotez, that I mentioned on top of the page):

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{enotez,multicol}
\usepackage{kantlipsum,microtype}


\usepackage[user,titleref]{zref}
\usepackage{xparse}
\let\oldchapter\chapter
\RenewDocumentCommand\chapter{som}{%
\IfBooleanTF{#1}
{\oldchapter*{#3}}
{%
  \IfNoValueTF{#2}
    {\oldchapter{#3}}
    {\oldchapter[#2]{#3}}%
    \refstepcounter{chapter}
  \zlabel{ch:\arabic{chapter}}%
}%
}

\NewSplitTitleTag{chapter title}{\ztitleref{ch:<split-level-id>}}
\setenotez{
  list-name = {},
  reset = true,
  split = chapter,
  split-title = {<chapter title>},
  mark-cs = {\textsuperscript}
}

\AtEveryEndnotesList{\begin{multicols}{2}} % before the whole list
\AfterEveryEndnotesList{\end{multicols}}   % after the whole list
\AfterEveryListSplit{\begin{multicols}{2}} % after a sub-heading in the splitted list
\AtEveryListSplit{\end{multicols}}         % before a sub-heading in the splitted list


\DeclareInstance{enotez-list}{custom}{paragraph}
{heading = \chapter*{#1},
notes-sep = 0\baselineskip,
format = \normalfont\footnotesize,
number = \textsuperscript{#1}
}

% column sep between columns in a multicols env:
\setlength\columnsep{22pt}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Superduper}
Text\endnote{\kant[1]}. Text\endnote{\kant[2]}.     
Text\endnote{\kant[3];\kant[4]}.
Text\endnote{\kant[5];\kant[6]}.

\chapter{Eher langweilig}
Text\endnote{\kant[1]}. Text\endnote{\kant[2]}.    
Text\endnote{\kant[3];\kant[4]}.
Text\endnote{\kant[5];\kant[6]}.

\newpage

\appendix
\chapter*{Anmerkungen}
\printendnotes[custom]

\end{document}
```